# how to retrieve the data from google places xml in android project

Tags: xml, google-places

I m using Google places with output as XML.i want to retrieve the data from XML .can anyone tell me how to perform that.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the setContentView(R.layout.main) in the onCreate method?

Comment: i can see that.what i meant is how to parse the data from xml output.which shows me the list of places....